# Problemas com Scroll View, como solucionar?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, syntax-error

Bom dia, sou novo com programação Android e estou tentando desenvolver um aplicativo em que, dependendo da matéria que o usuário escolher será aberta uma determinada tela, porém toda vez que o aplicativo tenta abrir essa página com as matérias, ele trava. 
Creio que o problema seja com o Scrooll View pois as outras telas que não tem, funcionam normalmente, no preview do Android Studio ela aparenta estar normal, quando deslizo com o mouse a tela desliza e tal porém ao rodar no aparelho as coisas são diferentes,enfim, agradeço se alguém puder ajudar.

[image: Print da tela que apresenta a falha]

Código da XML, atualmente ela está com o Layout ScroolView

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.caio.orculodosaber.pp"
tools:ignore="contentDescription"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

 <LinearLayout
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
     android:orientation="vertical">

                  <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">


                         <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonArte"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_arte"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"/>



                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonBiologia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_biologia"
                                android:onClick="obras"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonFilosofia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_filosofia"/>

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonFisica"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_fisica" />

                </LinearLayout>

                 <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonGeografia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:visibility="visible"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_geografia" />

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonHistoria"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_historia" />

                 </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonMatematica"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_matematica" 
                                   />

                        <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonPortugues"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_portugues"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"/>
                </LinearLayout>


                      <LinearLayout
                         android:layout_width="match_parent"
                         android:layout_height="match_parent"
                         android:orientation="horizontal">

                              <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonQuimica"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_quimica" />

                              <ImageButton
                                android:id="@+id/imageButtonSociologia"
                                android:layout_width="160dp"
                                android:layout_height="160dp"
                                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
                                android:background="@color/transparente"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:clickable="true"
                                android:onClick="obras"
                                app:srcCompat="@drawable/icone_sociologia" />

                      </LinearLayout>



        </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Código dá java:

```
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
 import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.Menu;
 import android.view.MenuItem;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Toast;

 public class pp extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_pp);


    }
```

Comment: Trava e fecha? Qual erro está mostrando no Android Studio?

Comment: Ele no Android Studio não aparece erro algum, como se estivesse ok, porém ao rodar no celular aparece que o app apresentou falhas continuamente ao abrir essa tela, e aí ele trava

Comment: Tem de abrir a janela de `Logcat` e ver o erro que apresenta quando ele trava. Coloque esse erro na pergunta.